# Fix error - Conversion failed when converting nvarchar value to date type int in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I'm getting this error:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
>   Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'PLANT001' to data type int

I tried adding convert and cast as int to the first line that's getting the error as well as the last join but I still get the error.

```
SELECT
    hh.PlantID AS 'Plant ID',
    hh.ERP AS 'ERP',
    hh.ShipViaID AS 'Ship Via ID',
    cc.carrier AS 'Carrier',
    cc.service AS 'Service',
    cc.packagetype AS 'Pkg Type',
    hd.HandlingChargeTypeID AS 'Handling Charge ID',
    hd.HandlingCharge 'Handling Charge',
    hr.AdditionalPercentageAdded 'Heading Addl % Added',
    hd.ApplyToEachPackage AS 'Apply to Each Pkg',
    hr.MinimumHandlingCharge AS 'Min Handling Charge',
    hr.MaximumHandlingCharge AS 'Max Handling Charge'
FROM 
    HandlingChargeHeader hh 
JOIN 
    HandlingChargeDetails hd ON hd.HandlingChargeHeaderID = hh.ID
JOIN 
    HandlingChargeRequirements hr ON hh.ID = hr.HandlingChargeHeaderID
LEFT JOIN 
    xcarrier_codes cc ON cc.ID = hh.ShipViaID AND hh.PlantID = cc.plantid
```

`cc.plantid` = `nvarchar`, `hh.plantid` = `int`

Comment: The right answer is  to change the datatype of the column, but you can use `TRY_CAST()` instead of `CAST()`

Comment: *"**cc.plantid = nvarchar, hh.plantid = int**"* There's your problem. Why are you storing a foreign key (which clearly isn't one, as you wouldn't be able to with a proper constraint) as an `int` in one table and an `nvarchar` in another? Correct the datatype and then add your foreign key constraints.

Comment: 'PLANT001' is a varchar value to cast will give error, how can you join them with different type of data? you can remove the characters before doing any convert or cast.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `try_convert()` :

```
select . . . 
from . . . 
     on . .  and
        try_convert(int, cc.plantid) = cc.plantid;
```

However, this seem doesn't solve your problem you need to convert this all time whenever the data required.

The recommended solution is to change your data model if it is possible with immediate effect.

Comment: Got a message that 'try_convert' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: Considering that the value is `'Plant001'` that is never going to convert to an `int`. @AndreaI. surely you aren't *still* using SQL Server 2008 (or older)? They are all completely (or very nearly) out of support. You should really be looking at an upgrade path soon if `TRY_CONVERT` isn't recognised.